Build customised legends in ggplot2
I have found quite a bit about customising legends, but nothing that helped me solve my specific issue with my plot legend.
I have wide data, and I want to display it using geom_tile().
wide_df <- data.frame(
  Person = c("A", "B", "C"),
  Q1 = c("yes", "no", "yes"),
  Q2 = c("often", "rarely", "never"),
  Q3 = c("cats", "cats", "dogs")
  )

I convert it to long using
long_df <- reshape2::melt(wide_df, id.vars = "Person")

and finally display it using geom_tile() as mentioned.
ggplot2::ggplot(long_df, aes(x = variable, y = Person, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()

The accompanying legend is not very useful.

I want to rearrange it and, most importantly, split it according to the original variables and add a title to each "sub-legend" (Q1: yes/no; Q2: never, rarely, often; Q3: cats/dogs).

One option would be to use the ggnewscale package which allows for multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic. But this requires to add the "tiles" for each sublegend via a separate geom_tile. Therefore I use purrr::imap to loop over the categories of variable to add the layers for each category:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

pal_fill <- scales::hue_pal()(length(unique(long_df$value))) |>
  setNames(sort(unique(long_df$value)))

guide_order <- seq(length(unique(long_df$variable))) |> 
  setNames(sort(unique(long_df$variable)))

ggplot(long_df, aes(x = variable, y = Person, fill = value)) +
  purrr::imap(
    split(long_df, ~variable),
    \(x, y) {
      list(
        ggnewscale::new_scale_fill(),
        geom_tile(data = x, aes(fill = value)),
        scale_fill_manual(
          values = pal_fill, name = y,
          guide = guide_legend(
            order = guide_order[[y]]
          )
        )
      )
    }
  )


